# How are two views shown after posting a question within a second?

Tags: discussion, questions, views

I generally noticed whenever I am posting a question and page going to refresh stackovershow

> view =2

[image]

While only I have just posted this question, how can view be 2? It should be 1.
Is it a bug or did Stack Overflow somehow add this by default for tracking something?

Comment: Why are you so sure this is a bug? Stack Overflow gets ***millions*** of visits a day. People sit there and refresh the homepage constantly, waiting for new questions to read. It's not unreasonable to expect a few views within a few seconds of posting.

Comment: There are a lot of users waiting for new questions so I can certainly see how you get 2 views instantly

Comment: @Matt sometime its acceptable but when we have used those tags which is not popular that time also i am getting same  its put confusion in my mind.

Comment: One of the views is yours (as soon as the quested is posted) you view it ;)

Comment: So  2 view means both views by me first before posting it and then after posting it

Comment: There's a Meta SE question on this from a few years ago. There was a suggestion that content-blockers from the user's side may be counting.

Comment: I've seen this as well, not sure if there's anything to it, but I always assumed that it was a crawler/automated process that accounted for the immediate view.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your *"How?"*:

Some people just watch the front page, and open every question that seems remotely interesting.

Basically, someone opened your question the moment they saw it appear.

Comment: But same happening with not popular tags in which few question posted and limited people watching that tags

Comment: And someone _still_ opened your question. Isn't that wonderful?

Comment: Within a second how someone can open a question Just posting and view is 2  :)\

Comment: ... I just told you. Someone else opened the question shortly after you posted it.

Comment: Can be done with this simple equation: (1Subodh Joshi + 1Other / 2 seconds)  = 2 Views)

Comment: Not everyone filters questions by tags, so the fact that you're using unpopular tags doesn't make it impossible, just a little less likely. Not to mention there are likely people following the unpopular tags you posted in too.